# Time Zone issue in cron

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am creating auction app where people can create their auctions on given date time from different locations.

I want to send notification to matched user for this auction but it's not working.
Please have a look on below cron which will run every minute.

For exp: I have created a auction which will begin `2017-09-06 10:05` Am so before auction start I want to send notification to matched user on `2017-09-06 10:04` but it's not working.

I have checked and found my auction time being conflicted with server time. Is there any way to fix it.

I have setup time zone based on user location in my app

```
public function actionCron()
    {
        $currentTime = time();
        $currentTimeFuture =$currentTime+90;
        $tableName = \backend\models\Delivery::tableName();

        $sql =  "select id,user_id,auction_start_time from $tableName where status=1 and is_delete=0 and delivery_status=0 and auction_start_time between $currentTime and $currentTimeFuture";

        $data = Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
        foreach($data as $_dilevery){
                // notification code here
        }
}
```

Comment: whatever times your users are seeing should be a function of the GUI. Internally you need to store your times in a consistent way (e.g. as UTC, or your server's timezone) otherwise you'll end up in a world of problems like this. Just convert them on the frontend into the user's preferred timezone at the moment that you display them. Likewise any input from the user, convert to the internal timezone before you store it. Then in your DB and any back-end actions like this example, the times are all consistent with each other.

Comment: "found my auction time being conflicted with server time" - what **exactly** does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky issue is trying to manage different processes in different timezones. To keep things simple it is highly recommended that you store all of your dates/times in UTC and that your servers also run in UTC. This allows for easy date comparisons and you never have to worry about tricky things like daylight savings, etc.

To make this more user friendly you should then ask your user what timezone they are in when the user signs up for your application. You can store this timezone and then use it to simply format all dates/times in your application to make things easier for the user.

Here is an example of taking a UTC date/time and easily changing it for different timezones: https://eval.in/855883

```
  // Store date/time as UTC
  $database_datetime = '2017-09-05 22:00:00';

  // Create a date/time object - TimeZone is UTC
  $dt = new DateTime($database_datetime, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
  echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); echo "\n\n";

  // Now change to user local date/time based on user timezone
  $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
  echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); echo "\n\n";

  $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
  echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); echo "\n\n";
```

Read more about PHP's `DateTime` here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

easy step.
save users Timezone in table.
and use Yii Formatter Class

*in main.config*

```
'formatter' => [
            'class'=>\common\components\Formatter::className(),
            'defaultTimeZone' => 'UTC',
            'timeZone' => 'UTC',
        ],
```

*create Formatter class in common\components*

*in controler*

```
 public function beforeAction($action)
    {$this->setTimeZone();
    }

 public function setTimeZone()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {            
            $timezone = Yii::$app->user->identity->timezone;
            if ($timezone && $timezone != Yii::$app->components['formatter']) {
                $formatter = Yii::$app->components['formatter'];
                $formatter['timeZone'] = $timezone;
                Yii::$app->setComponents(['formatter' => $formatter]);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting etting unknown property: common\components\Formatter::defaultTimeZone

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php -i |grep php\.ini
```

find the `php.ini` file for CLI version and choose your default timezone.